# Fill inputs on external iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I want to autofill textboxes on website when the iframe is loaded, it should fill in the input text forms.
(my app and the iframe are not in the same domain)
i want to know if there's a solution to make this feasible

Comment: Please be more specific and provide some code

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over both origins, then you can use the [`window.postMessage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between the iframe and the parent page.

If you do not have control over both origins, I don't think you can do that because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).